# Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2

Tags: printing, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After trying to install CUPS https://project-insanity.org/2022/11/01/use-cups-printing-server-on-windows-10/usbipd using which involved installing WSL Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS then usbipd https://openprinting.github.io/wsl-printer-app-compile/ using WSL in a Windows 11 environment, I am running into a roadblock after:

```
$usbipd wsl list
WARNING: usbipd not found for kernel 5.15.90.1-microsoft

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
    linux-cloud-tools-5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-standard-WSL2
    linux-cloud-tools-standard-WSL2
```

after that message I tried installing both recommended packages with no luck:

```
$sudo apt-get install linux-tools-5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-tools-5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2'
```

as recommended in another thread I also tried:

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-virtual hwdata
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/usbip usbip $(command -v ls /usr/lib/linux-tools/*/usbip | tail -n1) 20
```

Still no luck

I ran all the updates for Windows but no luck and there is no clarity if it even works with this version 23H2 (OS Build 22631.2506) of Win 11 with WSL. Should I or can I even downgrade any component to get it working or is there any other options?

Comment: The use of WSL, CUPS, and USBIP seems like a very convoluted way to install a printer on Windows. An introductory paragraph to the question that explains your grand vision might be very helpful. There may be simpler ways to achieve the goal.

Comment: USBIP on WSL: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb